# About flutter list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, methods

Can anybody please explain to me what operation does `list.from()` method performs. As I am a beginner I couldn't understand it.

I just wanna know about the `list.from()` method

```
Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
List<Post> posts = List<Post>.from(l.map((model)=> Post.fromJson(model)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`List.from` is creating a new list from the iterable given.

Please note that it was used in earlier versions, there is no reason for it today as it has some drawbacks.

This could be written as:

```
Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
final posts = l.map((model)=> Post.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

Or probably even shorter (speculating a bit here on what your other code looks like):

```
Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
final posts = l.map(Post.fromJson).toList();
```